# How does the benchmark calculate the proof size?

Tags: benchmarking, pov

I have no idea why this call uses such a lot proof size (around 4MB).

It looks like it doesn't change too many storage items.

https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia-messages-substrate/blob/e5d24b2fa56abf512fe944a7ab22ecd21f0eed66/modules/grandpa/src/lib.rs#L166

https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blame/fc35306420e515de56575c483c6fcfe8b357b285/runtime/crab/src/weights/pallet_bridge_grandpa.rs#L78

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see where the bulk part comes from:

```
BridgePolkadotGrandpa CurrentAuthoritySet (max_values: Some(1), max_size: Some(4000012), added: 4000507, mode: MaxEncodedLen)
```

It is using the `MaxEncodedLen` of that type to calculate the worst-case proof size. You configured `MaxBridgedAuthorities` to be [100k](https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/fc35306420e515de56575c483c6fcfe8b357b285/runtime/crab/src/pallets/bridge_grandpa.rs#L29).
That means it will assume the worst case to have 100k entries in the authority set - therefore resulting in 4 MB, which seems to be in line with 40 byte per authority from [here](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/9e1afcafb580b77379bebb60bb823f05c9ef8a16/bridges/modules/grandpa/src/storage_types.rs#L130).
I am not sure why 100k (or if that is a good number) but it should be possible to do post-dispatch correction with the [`unused_proof_size`](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/9e1afcafb580b77379bebb60bb823f05c9ef8a16/bridges/modules/grandpa/src/storage_types.rs#LL70C9-L70C26) function to refund the unused Proof weight.

The `MaxEncodedLen` is used since that represents the worst case. Note that benchmarking always has to consider the worst case scenario. There exists an alternative benchmarking mode; `measured` that will use the size of the actual accessed storage elements and add some overhead estimations on top. It looks like this: [`#[pov_mode = Measured]`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/be58e48f609c044fb832d78cf0f85c51e894d2dc/frame/benchmarking/pov/src/benchmarking.rs#L105) but should not be needed in 99% of cases.

Comment: I still feel weightv2 is very unstable and dangerous. Our production chain encountered this. Please check this https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/50707d071f95fe7cc57e72a5113d6c4f28fa527b/runtime/crab/src/weights/pallet_scheduler.rs#L100. This is crazy, we don't have sudo, and democracy use pallet-scheduler. Any schedule will fail. And we can't do runtime upgrade to fix this (because runtime upgrade requires a scheduler if there is no sudo). And this exists in official release polkadot-v0.9.40 branch.

Comment: Finally, we found that there is an inline preimage option. It could bypass the scheduler weight checks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And I want to learn more detail about how benchmark works to generate this. E.G. Why does it use `MaxEncodedLen` to calculate the size?

Comment: That weight for the scheduler looks wrong indeed. but you are running the benchmarking with `STEPS: 2, REPEAT: 1` that does not make any sense.  
It should indeed depend on `s`, which it also does in [polkadot-v0.9.40](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6e81199eac74ce9a7bf3b1c720989031dd9b18a1/frame/scheduler/src/weights.rs#L108).  
I will extend the answer later.

Comment: I added some sanity checks here that should error before that happens again https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/14408